# How to change the attributes of the <script> tag

Tags: javascript, html

Here is my script tag

```
<script
    src="https://checkout.razorpay.com/v1/checkout.js"
    data-key="abcd"
    data-amount="100"
    data-buttontext="Pay with Razorpay"
    data-name="Seven Atara"
    data-description="Website Purchase"
    data-image="https://your-awesome-site.com/your_logo.jpg"
    data-prefill.name="Harshil Mathur"
    data-prefill.email="support@razorpay.com"
    data-theme.color="#F37254"
    id="paymentWidget"
></script>
```

How can i change the value of `data-amount="100"` to my desired value

I tried like

```
document.getElementById("paymentWidget").attr("data-amount") = total
```

But it is showing error like

```
document.getElementById(...).attr is not a function
```

How can i fix this and set values dynamically ?

Comment: maybe something like `document.getElementById("paymentWidget")[0].setAttribute("data-amount", total)`

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen `getElementsById`?

Comment: FYI OP, you seem to be confusing [Jquery](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) to plain javascript

Comment: @George that is a simple type error from my side, sorry about that

Answer (score 2):

First include reference to the jquery library file.
Then rewrite the code as follows,

```
  $('#paymentWidget').attr("data-amount",desired-value);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
document.getElementById('paymentWidget').setAttribute('data-amount', total)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question is tagged with Jquery, but you're using plain JavaScript to get and element from the DOM

Try changing it to use a Jquery selector and setting the attribute correctly

```
$('#paymentWidget').attr('data-amount', total)
```

The reason your code isn't working is because you're trying to use the [Jquery method `.attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) on something which isn't a Jquery object.

Alternatively you could use [`.data`](https://api.jquery.com/data/)

```
$('#paymentWidget').data('amount', total)
```

The major difference is that `.data` will not change the DOM

Answer (score 0):

Right function is setAttribute, check its syntax bellow:

```
document.getElementById("paymentWidget").setAttribute('data-amount', total)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `dataset`. Data set is used when your attribute begins with `data-`.

In your example:

`document.getElementById("paymentWidget").dataset.amount = total;`

*Support for this is IE>11*

For more support use the `element.setAttribute("attribute", "value")`

Read more on MDN:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset